# Failing to Load Cloud-Related Functions

Tags: warning-messages, wolfram-cloud

I am running Mathematica 10.2 (Student Edition), and am encountering an issue with Cloud-related functions. Specifically, when I evaluate anything like CloudConnect or `$CloudConnected`, the output is whatever I input. I applied a Trace to it (which I saw someone do somewhere else when I was trying to troubleshoot something else), and this is the output:

```
In[1]: CloudConnect[] // Trace // Column
Out[1]:Get::noopen: Cannot open CloudObjectLoader` >>
{CloudConnect,Package`ActivateLoad[CloudConnect,{CloudObject`Utilities`RemoveAuthenticationInformation,CloudObject`Utilities`AuthenticationInformation,CloudObject`Utilities`AddAuthenticationInformation,CloudObject`Internal`RegisteredUserNameStatus,CloudObject`Internal`WolframUUIDStatus,CloudObject`Internal`WolframIDStatus,CloudObject`Internal`CloudConnectStatus,CloudObject`Internal`GetAuthentication,CloudObject`Internal`SetAuthentication,URLDispatcher,SetUsers,SetCloudDirectory,ScheduledTaskInformationData,ScheduledTaskInformation,ScheduledTasks,ScheduledTask,RestartInterval,ResponseForm,RemoveUsers,SharingList,CloudShare,CloudPublish,ClearPermissions,SetPermissions,PermissionsGroups,PermissionsGroup,Permissions,NotificationFunction,ReturnReceiptFunction,MailResponseFunction,MailReceiverFunction,LocalizeDefinitions,IncludeGeneratorTasks,IconRules,HTTPRedirect,HTTPErrorResponse,HTTPResponse,HTTPRequestData,GenerateHTTPResponse,GeneratorOutputType,GeneratorHistoryLength,GeneratorDescription,GeneratedDocumentBinding,ExportForm,ExternalBundle,EvaluationData,EpilogFunction,DocumentGenerators,DocumentGeneratorInformationData,DocumentGeneratorInformation,DocumentGenerator,DeliveryFunction,CachePersistence,Delayed,CreateUUID,CreatePermissionsGroup,ContinuousTask,CloudSymbol,CloudSubmit,CloudSave,CloudPut,CloudObjectInformationData,CloudObjectInformation,CloudObjects,CloudObject,CloudLoggingData,CloudImport,CloudGet,CloudFunction,CloudExport,CloudEvaluate,CloudDisconnect,CloudDirectory,CloudDeploy,CloudConnect,CloudAccountData,CloudBase,AutoRemove,AutoRefreshed,AddUsers,AbortScheduledTask,$RegisteredUserName,$PermissionsGroupBase,$Permissions,$HTTPRequest,$EvaluationEnvironmentParameters,$CloudSymbolBase,$CloudRootDirectory,$CloudCreditsAvailable,$CloudConnected},CloudObjectLoader`,{Package`HiddenImport->False,Path->Automatic}],CloudConnect}
CloudConnect[]
```

The Get::noopen error only shows up the first time I run any cloud type function. Afterwards, the only output is just identical to my input without the error message; if I have the Trace stuff after, then the output is completely empty. However, if I quit and restart the kernel, I am able to get this error on my first try again. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? I suspect some path somewhere is wrong, since I was able to find a file labelled CloudObjectLoader within the program files.

Comment: Have you created a [Wolfram Development Platform](https://develop.wolframcloud.com/app/) account?

Comment: I just checked via the link you provided; I have an account, but it's the Free one. Is that the problem (are free accounts not allowed to connect from Mathematica to the cloud)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Go to Mathematica > Help > Welcome Screen, click the SIGN IN to access your Wolfram Cloud files link in the top left corner, sign in with your username and password, and you should be good to go.

Comment: PS: You will probably also need to update Mathematica to the [current version](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html).

Comment: I should have made it clear: clicking that sign in button does nothing. It changes colour when I move my cursor over it as though it were click-able, but nothing occurs after clicking.